# Is it possible to render body with ajax in asp .net mvc project with layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to render body with ajax in asp .net mvc project with layout?

Comment: you need to render the whole page (with layout) via ajax ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but it doesn't make any sense as it will result in a completely broken and invalid markup. You will end up with a 2 headed and 2 body beast like Quazimodo. Actions that are requested view AJAX normally should return only partial views, not full views with layout. Or if you if you belong to some bandwidth saving party you could have your actions return JSON and then use a client side templating framework in order to lay out the markup.

Comment: Unless you replace the entire current page with the ajax result... Right? ;)

Comment: @AndersHolmström, that would absolutely kill the whole purpose of AJAX which is to refresh only certain portions of your DOM and thus save bandwidth :-) So yeah, as I said, it's possible but completely meaningless.

Comment: I thought the only point if AJAX was to remove that irritating address bar blink on page reload...

Comment: Personally this blink doesn't irritate me at all. Modern hardware and software make it almost unperceived. This very same site is a perfect example.

Comment: I agree, and I'm mostly poking fun. Sorry. ;)

Comment: I tried it, two heads is not useful :). is there a logical way to refresh content without submit?

Comment: @serefbilge, sure, you could use AJAX. That's what AJAX is meant for :-) Just make sure that your controller action that you are hitting with your AJAX request returns a PartialView.

Comment: I want to know one more thing. Is this site use ajax refresh when tab buttons(Questions, Tags, Users...) clicked? I asked this because layout of this page doesn't refresh when tab buttons are clicked.

Comment: No, this site doesn't use AJAX for those tabs. Just look at how the address bar changes when you click on the links. This means that those tabs are simple links redirecting to another page.

Comment: Thanks, how is it so fast? I can nat see any change when refreshing?

Comment: Look at my previous comment: modern hardware, software and fast broadband speed could make this almost unperceived. So here's how it happens: the SE network are using modern server hardware to host this site, in dedicated data centers, they wrote quality code on the server side in order to serve those pages as fast as possible (by caching the crap out of them), you on your side are probably having a fast internet connection and using a modern PC with a modern browser. That's how it happens.

Answer (score 1):

RenderBody is used on page postbacks to render a new HTML document with data from the server that has been annotated with the Razor templating engine. AJAX is used to retrieve data from the server asychronously (in a JSON format typically). An AJAX request can be used to retrieve the same data that RenderBody() would, but it wouldn't make much sense and isn't best practice.